# Solving the PDE $u_t=\|\nabla u\|_2^2$ (method of characteristics?)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hamilton-jacobi-equation

Suppose we wish to find a function $u(\vec x,t)$ on some domain $\Omega\times[0,\infty)$ satisfying the PDE $$u_t=\|\nabla u\|_2^2,$$ where $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$, and the gradient $\nabla$ is in the $\vec x$ independent variable.  We are given the initial information $u(\vec x,0)=u_0(\vec x)$ for a prescribed function $u_0:\Omega\to\mathbb R$, as well as Neumann boundary conditions $\nabla u(\vec x,t)\cdot\vec n(\vec x)=0$ for all $\vec x\in\partial \Omega$.

**Can we find a closed-form solution to this PDE, e.g. using the method of characteristics?**

Following the second example in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688943/use-the-method-of-characteristics-to-solve-nonlinear-first-order-pde) as well as [these course notes](https://people.cam.cornell.edu/%7Ezc227/extras/math6200_pres.pdf), it seems like the characteristic curves of this PDE satisfy:
$$
\begin{array}{rl}
u(t) &=-\|\vec c\|_2^2 t + D\\
\vec x(t) &=-2\vec c t + E,
\end{array}
$$
but I'm unclear on how to turn these into a solution to the PDE, and whether it's possible to incorporate the Neumann conditions.  One can read off a solution $u(\vec x,t)=\|\vec c\|_2^2 t + \vec x \cdot\vec c + D$ for a constant $\vec c$, but this does not satisfy arbitrary initial conditions or the Neumann conditions.

I did find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2395895/show-ux-t-to-0-where-u-solves-u-t-nabla-u2-0), which gives an expression that is close to a closed-form solution via the Hopf-Lax formula for a similar (but not identical) PDE.  Perhaps this is as close as we can get?

Comment: I think your chances of finding a closed form solution for an arbitrary $\Omega$ are slim to none. Did you have a specific $\Omega$ in mind?

Comment: Eventually I'd like to cook up a numerical solver for general domanis.  Even if there's no closed-form solution, any clues to the form of the solution can help!